# Adding object to paragraph style in InDesign

Tags: layout, adobe-indesign

I am trying to add a short underline in the paragraph style for my inline headlines. At the moment I am doing it with Paragraph Rules - rule below + offset and right indent (see attached image, the orange line). But this solution only works if the columns are always the same width.

Is there a way to add a object/line, with a defined width, to a paragraph style?

[image: Headline]

Answer (score 0):

Spontaneously, would say no. However that would be easy to set while adding some contents. You could however use a dedicated character style (underline) taht you would attach with agrep style to a tab character. Then you can control "rule" width with a tab position.

[image]

Comment: thank you :) Could you provide the grep style settings as well? I am still very new to grep, and find it hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Here it is…(and now just adding characters so stackoverflow will accept my if not too brief message…)

[image]

Comment: Thanks again. I still do not seem to get it to work. I should just be able to select my headline, and set the style, and then it would have the underline beneath it, right?  Could you show me the setting for the character style as well?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The fact is that you need to add a new line and type in a tab character. The presence of that tab will draw the "rule".

Answer (score 0):

Other solution is to use both "Above" and "Below" rules.
Playing with below's weight, color (white), offset and left indent would make it independent on column width (ruleAbove has entire column range)

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I would solve it:

1. Create a Stroke Style with Pattern Length = to the page size of your document (not text frame or column) and Length = to whatever length of your line should be.
   Example:
   Pattern Length = 8.5in (letter size paper)
   Length = 1in (width of line under paragraph)
2. Use Rule Under in the paragraph style and apply the stroke style you created. Make sure to set Width to "Text".
3. Apply any color/offset, etc. options.
   This will work independently of the text column width and text length.

Comment: @bummi. Thanks for formatting my answer. I believe -1 is for added work. The solution does work and tested nonetheless.